# Tab content reloading after clicking the tab

Tags: android, android-tabs

I'm working on an android app in which I created tabs dynamically using fragment.

The problem is that when I click on a tab, fill it's content, then click on another tab, and then come back to that tab, its data (like data filled for edit box etc.) disappears because the tab is reloaded again.

How do I make my filled-in data not disappear on changing the tabs?

Is it possible to make it such that the tabs are not reloaded every time the tabs are clicked?

Please, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this -

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3); // where 3 is the total number of tabs
```

Comment: I'm not using ViewPager to create tabs.